# Error while using IBM language translator in my project. Error :AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'TLSVersion'

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I am facing an error in ibm_watson api which throws a error whenever I run this code:

```
import json
from ibm_watson import LanguageTranslatorV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

apikey="tDc3PeMIIGCoTfNU7emYTw8cBLO4rZdVPiBiuvO2LBu6"
url="https://api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/ad9dda42-945e-471e-b6a7-6fd0edadeeec"

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
language_translator = LanguageTranslatorV3(version='2018-05-01',authenticator=authenticator)
language_translator.set_service_url(url)

translation = language_translator.translate(text='Hello, how are you today?',model_id='en-fr').get_result()

print(json.dumps(translation, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

def englishToFrench(englishText):
    frenchText = language_translator.translate(
    text=englishText,
    model_id='en-fr').get_result()
    print(json.dumps(frenchText, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    return frenchText

def frenchToEnglish(frenchText):
    englishText = language_translator.translate(
    text=frenchText,
    model_id='en-fr').get_result()
    print(json.dumps(englishText, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    return englishText
```

Error after running the code:

```
theia@theiadocker-atharva14122:/home/project/xzceb-flask_eng_fr/final_project/machinetranslation$ python3 translator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translator.py", line 9, in <module>
    language_translator = LanguageTranslatorV3(version='2018-05-01',authenticator=authenticator)
  File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_watson/language_translator_v3.py", line 76, in __init__
    authenticator=authenticator)
  File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.http_adapter = SSLHTTPAdapter()
  File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/utils.py", line 35, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.init_poolmanager(pool_connections, pool_maxsize, block=pool_block)
  File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/utils.py", line 42, in init_poolmanager
    ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'TLSVersion'
theia@theiadocker-atharva14122:/home/project/xzceb-flask_eng_fr/final_project/machinetranslation$
```

Expected output should be translation from english to frenchie, Output should be Some text in french in my case

Bonjour comment vas tu aujourd'hui?

---

Answer (score 1):

It's because the servers of IBM don't have the correct libraries. My solution was open the embedded ubuntu that has windows 10. I recommend you uses embedded ubuntu of windows 10 or an real linux server.